# C++ generating rand numbers

Tags: c++, random, blackjack

In C++ is it possible to use rand to generate a number between 1-52, but stating that it cant be 23? Like for instance creating a blackjack game, you would need to make sure a player cant get the same card after randomly generating the first.

Comment: I just reread this. I think the OP means that after 23 is drawn, it shouldn't come up again.

Answer (score 13):

Sure.

```
int i = 23;
while (i == 23)
    i = rand() % 52 + 1;
```

It's quite common to discard unacceptable values when generating random numbers with a required distribution.

For a blackjack game, though, you need to deal more than one card. It's better to have a full deck and shuffle it ([`std::random_shuffle`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/random_shuffle)), then take cards from one end of whatever container holds the deck.

Comment: I still dont see how it is excluding 23, let look at it this way:

card1 = rand() % 52 + 1;

Comment: @MichaelRamos - if the generated value is 23 it tries again. This is a more dense version of the solution sketched by deadlock.

Comment: so i could do: card1 = 

rand() % 52 + 1;

Comment: so i could do: 

card1 = rand() % 52 + 1;
card2 = rand() % 52 + 1;
    while card2 == card1;
    card2 = rand() % 52 + 1;

Comment: More generally, create a deck of cards in, say, an `std::array<card> deck`, initialized with all 52 cards. Then call `std::random_shuffle(deck.begin(), deck.end())`. Then deal cards with an index into the `array` object. First card is `deck[0]`, second card is `deck[1]`, third card is `deck[2]`, etc.

Comment: i would do so, but this is an assignment for a beggener course, i am not able to make the program out of c++ components that we have not learned

Comment: @MichaelRamos - fair enough. If the goal is **only** to draw two cards without a repetition, then most of the answers you've gotten will work. I like the simplicity of Mike's for this particular case, but it's harder to extend if you need to draw more than two cards.

Comment: Wouldn't a `do-while` loop be more natural here?

Comment: @FredOverflow - maybe. `do-while` loops always feel unnatural to me. `<g>`

Comment: @MichaelRamos: Please state your course's constraints in an edit to your question so that we can help you work within them. There's no need to ask the same question multiple times on StackOverflow.

Answer (score 4):

```
int value = rand(1,51);
if (value >= 23) ++value;
```

where `rand(a,b)` gives a number in the range `[a,b]`, and could be implemented as `std::rand() % (b-a+1) + a`, with the caveat that that wouldn't quite be a uniform distribution.

Comment: That's a uniform distribution over the allowed values; which is what you want if you're modelling a deck of cards.

Comment: `rand()` doesn't take any arguments.

Comment: @PeteBecker: Sorry, I wrote the answer in a bit of a hurry and didn't explain that it's pseudocode for "random number between two values". It could be implemented as `std::rand() % 51 + 1`.

Comment: @MikeSeymour: however that would __not__ be uniformly distributed.

Comment: @MikeSeymour let look at it this way, because im not getting how the second card generation would exclude the first card picked:

card1 = rand() % 52 + 1;   I now want to do card2 = rand() % 52 + 1; but it cant be the smae number as card1

Comment: @nightcracker - it's close enough for a card game.

Comment: @nightcracker: Which is one reason why I didn't specify an implementation of it.

Comment: @PeteBecker: Depends how much money is on the line.

Comment: I like this solution because it manages to fit the restrictions with only one call of `rand`. To handle more than one excluded value `x` you would have to add a loop `if (value >= x) ++value;` over all `x` in a sorted list (lowest first).

Comment: @MichaelRamos The first line picks a random number from a smaller range, `[1,51]` rather than `[1,52]`; the second adjusts that range to exclude 23 and include 52.

Comment: @Auwald: let's say `RAND_MAX` is 64 (for demonstration purposes). Because `(64 % 52) == 12` the values 0 to 11 have twice the propability to occur than the values 12-51 if you calculate the value by `rand() % 52`. Now this effect is a lot less noticable when `RAND_MAX` is large, it is still there. An even worse problem with range reduction using modulo is that it grabs the lower bits of the RNG, which tend to be really really bad with stdlib's `rand()`.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a program that makes a deck from 1 to 52 (inclusive) and prints the deck.
This features STL (and a slightly dated C++ accent)

```
#include <algorithm>    // std::random_shuffle
#include <ctime>        // std::time
#include <cstdlib>      // std::rand, std::srand
#include <iostream>     // std::cout
#include <vector>       // std::vector

int main() {
    std::vector<int> deck;

    // Create deck; deck creation logic goes inside loop
    for (int i = 1; i <= 52; ++i) {
        deck.push_back(i);
    }

    // initialize random number generator and shuffle deck
    std::srand(std::time(0));
    std::random_shuffle(deck.begin(), deck.end());

    // print entire deck
    while (!deck.empty()) {
        int card = deck.back();    // draw card
        std::cout << "Drew " << card << '\n';
        deck.pop_back();           // remove card from deck
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
int n=(rand() % 52)+ 1;
while(n==23)
n= n=(rand() % 52) + 1;
```

http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdlib/rand/

Comment: `rand()` doesn't take any arguments.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at `std::random_shuffle`.

Answer (score 0):

Another cool way to do this is with an array.

Create a vector:

```
std::vector<int> possibilities;
```

Insert possible values to it:

```
possibilities.push_back(0);
possibilities.push_back(1);
possibilities.push_back(10);
```

And then pick a random one from it:

```
int random = possibilites[ rand() % possibilites.size() ];
```