# While Loop, and gen rand()

Tags: c++, loops, random, while-loop

So im basically creating a game of blackjack, im stuck where i must ask the user if he wants another card (Take a HIT), ive decided to do a while loop. A problem i am trying to figure out is how i can make it so the random number that was chosen for the first HIT, can't be chosen again, im stuck because i am assigning that variable to "card3"

```
while (hit == 'yes' || hit == 'Yes' || hit =='Y' || hit == 'y')
{
//create new card, add onto total, ask again
card3 = rand() % 51 + 1;
while (card3 == card1 || deal1 == card2 || card3 == deal1){
  card3 = rand() % 52 + 1;
}
if (card3 == 1 || card3 == 2 || card3 == 3 || card3 == 4){
cout <<"|A|";
total = total + 11;}
else if (card3 == 5 || card3 == 6 || card3 == 7 || card3 == 8){
cout <<"|2|";
total = total + 2;}
else if (card3 == 9 || card3 == 10 || card3 == 11 || card3 == 12){
cout <<"|3|";
total = total + 3;}
else if (card3 == 13 || card3 == 14 || card3 == 15 || card3 == 16){
cout <<"|4|";
total = total + 4;}
else if (card3 == 17 || card3 == 18 || card3 == 19 || card3 == 20){
cout <<"|5|";
total = total + 5;}
else if (card3 == 21 || card3 == 22 || card3 == 23 || card3 == 24){
cout <<"|6|";
total = total + 6;}
else if (card3 == 25 || card3 == 26 || card3 == 27 || card3 == 28){
cout <<"|7|";
total = total + 7;}
else if (card3 == 29 || card3 == 30 || card3 == 31 || card3 == 32){
cout <<"|8|";
total = total + 8;}
else if (card3 == 33 || card3 == 34 || card3 == 35 || card3 == 36){
cout <<"|9|";
total = total + 9;}
else if (card3 == 37 || card3 == 38 || card3 == 39 || card3 == 40){
cout <<"|10|";
total = total + 10;}
else if (card3 == 41 || card3 == 42 || card3 == 43 || card3 == 44){
cout <<"|J|";
total = total + 10;}
else if (card3 == 45 || card3 == 46 || card3 == 47 || card3 == 48){
cout <<"|Q|";
total = total + 10;}
else if (card3 == 49 || card3== 50 || card3 == 51 || card3 == 52){
cout <<"|K|";
total = total + 10;}
cout << endl;
cout <<"Your total is: " << total << endl;
cout <<"Would you like another card? yes or no: " << endl;
cin >> hit; 
cout << endl;
}
```

Comment: Is this some schoolwork with constraints set, or are you learning on your own?

Comment: @hyde this is schoolwork

Comment: possible duplicate of [C++ generating rand numbers](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15118795/c-generating-rand-numbers)

Comment: @Johnsyweb no this is pertaining to taking a hit, not generating the users second card

Comment: Dealing a third, fourth, ... fifty-first random card from a shuffled deck... it's all the same.

Comment: @Johnsyweb Its not anymore now that it is inside a while loop, the hit need to happen in a while loop

Answer (score 2):

You could put all the cards in a container, then use [`std::random_shuffle`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/random_shuffle) to, well, shuffle them. Then pop one card at a time from the back of the container. When the deck is done, start again.

Comment: Unfortuantly i can only do what we have been taught in class, so pretty much if statements and loops

Comment: @MichaelRamos then you should state your requirements clearly in the question because they are quite artificial.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like an exercise in which you should use an array. I can't write the program for you, but read up on arrays - they are an important part of the solution. You can make an array of 52 boolean variables that indicates which cards have been picked. You ought to devise an algorithm that checks whether a card has been picked, and while we're getting a random picked card, keep picking a new one.

Comment: we have not covered arrays, therefore i cant use them